# Having trouble getting my jQuery plugin to work. TypeError: $(...).functionName is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Granted I haven't seen this code in quite a while, but I can't think of what I'm doing wrong it worked perfectly when I first built it:

```
// scrollio.js
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollio = function() {
     $button = $('.scrollio');
     $button.on('click', function() {
       var scrollTo = $(this).attr('data-scroll');
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#' + scrollTo).offset().top
       }, 1000);
     });
  };
})(jQuery);

// using the plugin in script.js

(function($) {
    $('.scrollio').scrollio();
})(jQuery);
```

File order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollio.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

No matter what I do I always get:

```
TypeError: $(...).scrollio is not a function
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Works just fine for me, are you sure the script files are loading

Comment: [Works just fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/0vw5mLfg/). Verify that you're loading the scripts in the right order.

Comment: ^ also verify they're in the right directory path

Comment: I have never heard about a 'scrollio' plugin. Are you sure that this is correct and you must say 'scrollTo'

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It seems like everything is loading. But I'm still getting the error. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @Franco Haha I know, it's a custom plugin I built

Comment: I'm loading everything in the same order as in the OP, but it's still a no go for some reason.

Comment: That's i what I was just thinking. Maybe it will better if you post it here, so we can see if you are addressing this 'scrollio' function correctly. Anyway, nice name for a plugin

Comment: @Franco He did post it. It's in the top of the code section he posted.

Comment: Can you post full html of your page to see where and how your scripts are included?

Comment: Wow!!! I am blind. All day behind this screen is not very healthy. Thanks @Mike

Comment: @Franco I just did a test, and it seems like the 'script.js' is firing before 'scrollio.js' is being loaded. Idk why

Comment: @DevonAero - please put whole html of your page into question. Without it it is hard to explain loading order issues.

Comment: @Dmitry Edited the OP. I also tried it on Codepen and it works perfectly.

Comment: I definitely recommend you to move all libraries (e.g. jQuery and your plugin) into head section of HTML + move all initializing (like in script.js) inside document.ready event handler. Let me know if this solve issue.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the help man! I moved it to the bottom to help page speed, but the document.ready() solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to intialize the plugin in this way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.scrollio').scrollio();
    })
</script>
```

and well on the bottom of your page

And delete this from script.js:

```
(function($) {
    $('.scrollio').scrollio();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: With the same effect - code could be moved inside document ready event while remaining in script.js file. This will likely help but doesn't explain original problem.

Comment: Can you now use your plugin?

Comment: @Franco, that got rid of the TypeError, but now the plugin's not working.. The code in the OP works perfect on CodePen.

Comment: Nvm, I had a typo in "scr" haha. Thanks so much @Franco!